# mlogit duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Tags: r, duplicates, mlogit

New to R and want to use `mlogit` function.

However after putting my data into a data frame and run

```
x <- mlogit.data(mlogit, choice="PlacedN", shape="long", alt.var="RaceID")
```

I get  `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`

I can upload my file if needed I've spent days trying to get this to work, so any help will be appreciated

Comment: It would be better to have a reproducible example/file to check the problem.

Comment: so you could change the row names or try a matrix instead which allows duplicate row names (might not work since the docs say the input needs to be a data frame)

Comment: @akrun please go to the link it called mlogit thanks for any help [link](https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pl/cubbug/_55429662ff9641e2b9923e1bc63941ec)

Comment: There's only a csv file there. Which may disappear at any moment, making this question obsolete. Please make your question reproducible by including simulated data. This is also a great tool for you to learn about your data.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to put `"RaceID"` into the `alt.levels` argument instead of `alt.var`.  From the `mlogit.data` help file:

> `alt.levels`
>
> the name of the alternatives: if null, for a wide data.frame, they are guessed from the variable names and the choice variable (both should be the same), for a long data.frame, they are guessed from the alt.var argument.

Give this a try.

```
library(mlogit)
m <- read.csv("mlogit.csv")
mlogd <- mlogit.data(m, choice="PlacedN", shape="long", alt.levels="RaceID")
head(mlogd)
#            RaceID PlacedN   RSP TrA JoA aDS bDS mDS aDH bDH mDH LDH  MR eMR
# 1.RaceID 20119552    TRUE  3.00  13  12   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 131
# 2.RaceID 20119552   FALSE  4.00  23  26  91  94  94 139 153 145 153 150 150
# 3.RaceID 20119552   FALSE  0.83  15  15  99 127  99 150 153 150 153 159 159
# 4.RaceID 20119552   FALSE 18.00  21  15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 131
# 5.RaceID 20119552   FALSE 16.00  16  12  92 127  92 134 135 134 135 136 136
# 6.RaceID 20119617    TRUE  2.50  12  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 152
```

Comment: Thanks it loaded ok but when I went to try    summary(mlogit(PlacedN~TrA+JoA -1,data=x))       I get Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "RaceID") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: @Michael - that code is completely different from what you have in your question

Comment: Please ask a new question related to that because that's a new separate task

Comment: @RichScriven The OP is pointing out a problem in your answer, namely that specifying the column name in `alt.levels` creates a column of "alternatives" that has only one value: the column name. That isn't helping get any closer to solving the problem.