# Does R's mlogit deal with multi-sized set of unique alternatives?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, mlogit

Customers are faced with series of choices of unique alternatives. For example:

Customer 1 chooses between alternatives A1,A2,A3,A4; 
Customer 1 chooses between atlernatives B1,B2; 
Customer 2 chooses between alternatives C1,C2,C3; 
Customer 2 chooses between alternatives D1,D2,D3 
etc

Can any R package deal with it?

For example.csv

```
CHOICE,CUSTOMER,CHID,ALT,DIST,INCOME
1,1,1,1,100,70
0,1,1,2,372,70
0,1,1,3,417,70
0,1,1,4,180,70
1,1,2,1,68,70
0,1,2,2,354,70
0,2,3,1,68,100
0,2,3,2,354,100
1,2,3,3,399,100
1,2,4,1,180,100
0,2,4,2,100,100
0,2,4,3,80,100
```

*mlogit* failed

```
> library(mlogit)
> ExData <- read.csv("C:/Users/John/Desktop/R/example.csv")
> MLData <- mlogit.data(ExData, shape="long", choice="CHOICE", chid.var="CHID", id.var="CUSTOMER", alt.var="ALT")
> res <- mlogit(CHOICE~DIST|INCOME, data=MLData, shape="long", alt.var="ALT")
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(chid, alt, sep = ".")) : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘2.1’, ‘2.2’, ‘3.3’
```

while for example1.csv where the number of alternatives is constant

```
CHOICE,CUSTOMER,CHID,ALT,DIST,INCOME
1,1,1,1,100,70
0,1,1,2,372,70
0,1,1,3,417,70
0,1,2,1,180,70
1,1,2,2,68,70
0,1,2,3,354,70
0,2,3,1,68,100
0,2,3,2,354,100
1,2,3,3,399,100
1,2,4,1,180,100
0,2,4,2,100,100
0,2,4,3,80,100
```

everything is fine.

Comment: This main thrust of your question does not appear appropriate for SO, which is a "forum" for focused questions on programming problems. Please consider removing this question and posting a modified version on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) which would be more appropriate for questions on statistical methodology. I'm fairly sure that what your data cannot be modeled by a multinomial logit, regardless of the software involved. Translating into a binary outcome, we get that customers make a choice to purchase a distinct item from the menu with no overlap in the choice set.

Comment: Thanks @lmo. I hope that multinomial logit can't deal with my data. At least [this paper](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/courses2/crp5700/5700-mlogit.pdf) mentions varying choice sets

Comment: based on rich-scriven's suggestion, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440404/mlogit-duplicate-row-names-are-not-allowed), this seems to work. `mlogit(CHOICE~DIST|INCOME, data=MLData, shape="long", alt.levels=unique(exData$ALT))`. Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @lmo, thanks a lot. It works now. However I start to doubt if the specification of my model is correct...

Comment: Yeah. I'm not too familiar with this model and just started to read about it. At least for the `mnlogit` package, it appears that each "choice situation" must present the same choice set in each instance. Using `alt.levels` here may be forcing a balanced panel.

Comment: @lmo, as the alternatives are not categorized I start to doubt that multinomial logit is applicable in my case...

Comment: Take a look at my initial comment. I'd suggest that you post a statistical modelling question on CV. Describe your data in some detail -- sample size, choice set, etc. -- and then mention that you are investigating the use of multinomial logit but are concerned about certain issues (explain issues) and then ask if another model may be more appropriate.

Comment: @lmo, I've tried once but got no answer. Anyway thanks, I'll try once again.